# Why broadcast receiver is not working in background after app closed in Android 6.0+?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-broadcastreceiver

The problem is actually in broadcast receiver in Android marshmallow.

```
<receiver android:name="CallReceiver" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:exported="true" 
    android:stopWithTask="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="YouNeverKill"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>                    
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Any one Help me where is actuall problem.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> please add this permission

Comment: @Narendra talapara your targetSdk?

Comment: You might be checking this after running your project directly into a device. Either make an apk and install it or open your application from settings's menu and apply all the required permission. in 6+ version by default all permissions are not granted.

Answer (score 0):

Because Android-M i.e. 6+ versions require runtime permissions.You can refer below document:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en